# Jquery data table buttons not showing up in UI

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

In jquery data tables excel,copy and pdf buttons not showing other than this every thing works fine what could be the issue.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('.export-table').DataTable({

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            'bServerSide': true, 
            'sAjaxSource': 'api', 
            buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf']

        });

       table.buttons().container().appendTo('#export-table_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)');

    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the thread here:-https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29513/buttons-extension-not-showing-up

Comment: Tried but did'nt work

Comment: Add dom: 'Bfrtip' in your code.

Comment: dom: 'Bfrtip' works fine but when I download data it shows only 10 records in the file. Showing only first 10 records in the excel which are visible on the screen.

Comment: All data is not getting downloading only 10 records are coming what could be the issue